# Is it possible to access route params within component import in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a particular route in my router that looks like :

```
{
      path: '/product/:name',
      component: () => import(`@/modules/analysis/views/products/${nameParam}.vue`),
      name: RouteNameConstants.Product
     
}
```

I have the different `.vue` files in the products folder, is it possible to access the `name param` in the component import statement ?
So that for example when i visit /product/abc , the component import resolves as `@/modules/analysis/views/products/abc.vue`  ?

Comment: You have no control over that in `component` property. Make a wrapper component and use dynamic <component is>